# EntityFramework.Core.Tools nuget package installation error: "The process cannot access the file ef.exe because it is being used by another process"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core, entity-framework-core, nuget-package, ef-core-3.1

While installing the package **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools** for using EF in my project using Nuget, I'm persistently running into the below error. Notice I didn't get any error while installing other related packages used for EF core

- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer

[image: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Error]

Here is the location of the file **ef.exe**

[image: EF.Core.exe]

Basically the intention behind installing this package is to use EF command-line tools. I'm currently on Windows 10 and the .NET SDK installed on my machine is 3.1. I had previously 2 SDK's installed on my system(3.1 & 5.0). As per [microsoft's documentaion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/selection), **"The .NET CLI must choose an SDK version for every dotnet command. It uses the latest SDK installed on the machine by default."** Therefore I went ahead and uninstalled .NET 5.0 SDK

[image: Dot.Net.Core.SDK.version]

### Here are some of the solutions that I tried:

1. Deleting the package folder from ***'.nuget/packages/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.tools'*** & thereby the executable i.e. **'ef.exe'** and reinstalling the same.
2. Installing the same package using dotnet cli.
3. Running Visual Studio 2019 as admin.
4. Deleted the folder **"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions"**

I have also tried some of the steps mentioned here on github: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1138
. Any kind of help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have answered the detailed description of the solution here on microsoft's .NET Q&A platform.
['EntityFramework.Core.Tools' nuget package installation error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/397721/39entityframeworkcoretools39-nuget-package-install.html)